# What is the difference between "count" and other variable say "i"?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C and I was going through a source code for finding HCF of two numbers.

```
{
    int num1, num2, i, hcf;
    printf("Enter two integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    for(i=1; i<=num1 || i<=num2; ++i)
    {
        if(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0)  
            hcf=i;
    }
    printf("H.C.F of %d and %d is %d", num1, num2, hcf);
    return 0;
```

Here we used `i`, but in most of the programs we use `count`. Can we use `count` here as well? ... and what is the difference?

Comment: do you mean that the variable name was changed ?

Comment: Variable names can be anything (as long as they are valid variable names, of course; there are some restrictions due to reserved words and symbols and so on), the compiler doesn't care. The names have no meaning, it's all in how they are used.

Comment: there is no restriction about how you use a variable. It all comes down to logic. Count is a variable and so is i ... same logic can be implemented usinng them ... there will be no error even if you replace the variable i with your name even :)

Comment: [Programming variables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables)

Comment: Variable names cannot be anything. The compiler cares. You cannot use reserved keywords as variable name.

Comment: @kkamilpl True, I edited my comment for accuracy.

Comment: @gurpinder singh What does abbreviation HCF mean?:) For example I found in a dictionary the following health care finder :)

Answer (score 1):

In your context, `i` and/or `count` are variable names. They don't hold any *special* meaning. You can use *almost* any word you like as a variable name, until and unless it is a *keyword*.

For a detailed information, you can have a look at `C11` standard, chapter 6.4, *"Lexical elements"* and especially chapter 6.4.2, *"Identifiers"*